# Set value of TextEditingController from navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

In my first page I have this:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) =>
               UpdateAttackScreen(
                  idAttack: idAttack,
                  title: title,
                  descriptionAttack:descriptionAttack,
                  indexSensations:indexSensations)));
               },
```

in the second page where I want to receive this params:

```
class UpdateAttackScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idAttack;
  final String title;
  final String descriptionAttack;
  final List<dynamic> indexSensations;

  UpdateAttackScreen(
      {Key key,
      @required this.idAttack,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.descriptionAttack,
      @required this.indexSensations})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpdateAttackScreenState createState() => _UpdateAttackScreenState(idAttack, title, descriptionAttack, indexSensations);
}

class _UpdateAttackScreenState extends State<UpdateAttackScreen> {
  String idAttack;
  String title;
  String descriptionAttack;
  List<dynamic> indexSensations;
  _UpdateAttackScreenState(idAttack, title, descriptionAttack, indexSensations);

  TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController()..text = title;
  TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController()..text = descriptionAttack;
```

The response error on **title** and **descriptionAttack**:

**The instance member 'title' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

Wrap **`_titleController`** with **`initState`** method

```
 String title = '';
 TextEditingController _titleController;
   
  @override
  void initState() {
    _titleController..text = title;
    super.initState();
  }
```

**Solution 2:**

Transform the **`title`** variable into a **`static variable`** to be able to use it everywhere in your class

```
static String title = '';
 TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController()..text = title ;
```

Comment: the value return null

Comment: @joisberg what about the second solution ? I just update my answer

Comment: Return = "" --> [photo](https://imgur.com/a/XmWIvMl)

Comment: please what do you want to do with your title ? . replace ' ' with your default title name . If you want to change the value , you can easily do it inside setState method in Button or anything else

Comment: I want to create a TextFieldForm for update the title and I want to precompile this TextFieldForm with value.

`TextFormField(controller: _titleController, initialValue: title);`

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
 TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController()..text = title;
    TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController()..text = descriptionAttack;
```

replace with this

```
 TextEditingController _titleController;
  TextEditingController _descriptionController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _titleController = TextEditingController()..text = title;
    _descriptionController = TextEditingController()..text = descriptionAttack;
  }
```

Comment: `_titleController = TextEditingController()..text = title` return null

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it!**

```
class UpdateAttackScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idAttack;
  final String title;
  final String descriptionAttack;
  final List<dynamic> indexSensations;

  UpdateAttackScreen(
      {Key key,
      @required this.idAttack,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.descriptionAttack,
      @required this.indexSensations})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpdateAttackScreenState createState() => _UpdateAttackScreenState(idAttack, title, descriptionAttack, indexSensations);
}

class _UpdateAttackScreenState extends State<UpdateAttackScreen> {
  String idAttack;
  String title;
  String descriptionAttack;
  List<dynamic> indexSensations;
  _UpdateAttackScreenState(idAttack, title, descriptionAttack, indexSensations);

  TextEditingController _titleController;
  TextEditingController _descriptionController;
```

Inside the **TextFieldForm**

```
initialValue: widget.title,
```